# Glitch in the Ubuntu 14.04 Install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, dvd

I have a 2013 ASUS 64bit system with Windows 7 (Home Prem.) Sp1, 16GB Ram, 3.40 gigahertz Intel Core i7-4770 processor.
I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 from the official site. Ran MD5SUM and numbers matched. Burned .iso file to DVD with Windows Disk Image Burner and verified as ok. Partitioned 248GB as unallocated on my C: drive. Shut down system and re-booted. Set boot to DVD drive. Black screen pops up with ":Boot LOGO - Initialization" and then screen goes to Ubuntu (logo) and 5 dots below it. The dots sequentially blink white to red. I can hear DVD drive spinning. After a few minutes, the lights all turn red and the drive stops. The screen freezes up. I pressed ESC and there is a page full of computer lingo, such as:

166.3485] [fff and a bunch more of hex stuff]:do_IRO+0x4d/0xc0

I'd really like to install and use Ubuntu, but after three solid days, this install attempt is getting old!!! Don't know if it's an error, me, Norton Anti-virus settings, etc.Suggestions?????????

Comment: Just a hunch, but try running a memory diagnostic (It's most probably a bad disc, but it doesn't hurt to try).

Answer (score 0):

try disabling fast startup in bios and then try, boot using the dvd, 
alternatively you could make a usb bootable using unetbootin
I had the same problem, but unetbootin fixed  it http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
here is the link
hope it works, good luck